# delete each line after the click on Delete button

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child

I wanted to delete each line after clicking its corresponding delete. I couldn't track the parent-child things. What is wrong in my code?

My HTML

```
    <div class="li">
        <li> Apple <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Ball <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Cat <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Dog <button>Delete</button></li>
    </div>
```

JS

```
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
console.log(btn)
btn.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("Hi there boys.")
        let prnt = document.querySelectorAll('.li li')
        for(let i = 0; i<prnt.length; ++i)
        {
            // console.log(prnt[i].parentNode.children)
            prnt.removeChild(prnt[i].parentNode.firstElementChild)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. `div` is not a permitted parent of [`li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the parent of the button, and then from the parent you can get the container. Then just remove the parent from the container.

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')
btns.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const parent = element.parentElement;
    const container = parent.parentElement;
    container.removeChild(parent);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="li">
  <li> Apple <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li> Ball <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li> Cat <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li> Dog <button>Delete</button></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have made things complicated,just need to use `element.parentNode.remove()` can do it

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')
btns.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        element.parentNode.remove()
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="li">
        <li> Apple <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Ball <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Cat <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Dog <button>Delete</button></li>
    </div>
```